# Does spring security provide out of the box feature to retrieve and use OAuth2 token from a resource server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices

We have a Springboot application (let’s say microservice-A) and there is a requirement that we should add a HTTP Authorisation header with the OAuth2 token to access one of our other microservice (let’s say microservice-B). Also we are said that we can retreive this OAuth2 token by sending a HTTP POST request with Grant_type, Scope and basic authentication username and password to the same microservice-B.

Now my doubt is, do we have any kind of out of the box support from Spring security to automatically retrieve this OAuth2 token from microservice-B   whenever it expires and send the subsequent HTTP requests. Or is this not required at all and I should just retrieve the OAuth2 token first by sending a normal HTTP POST request from microservice-A and then send the subsequent requests. (This way I might have to retrieve the OAuth2 token every time I want to send a request or save the token and retrieve it when it expires)

Microservice-A is the “client"
Microservice-B is the “resource server”

Comment: Have you seen the reference docs for [OAuth 2.0 Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks it helped @SteveRiesenberg
Used client_credentials grant type flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`. Below are the configurations required to configure a OAUTH2 based WebClient that can automatically fetch the OAUTH2 token from auth-server (Microservice-B) and access resource-server (Microservice-B).

**application.properties**

```
oauth2.client.registration.pgw.scope=all
oauth2.client.registration.pgw.client-id=client
oauth2.client.registration.pgw.client-secret=secret
oauth2.client.provider.pgw.token-uri=http://localhost:8082/oauth/token
```

**Oauth2ClientConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class Oauth2ClientConfiguration {
        
    @Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository getRegistration(
            @Value("${oauth2.client.provider.pgw.token-uri}") String tokenUri,
            @Value("${oauth2.client.registration.pgw.client-id}") String clientId,
            @Value("${oauth2.client.registration.pgw.client-secret}") String clientSecret,
            @Value("${oauth2.client.registration.pgw.scope}") String scope) {
        
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                                                .withRegistrationId(OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID)
                                                .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                                                .clientId(clientId)
                                                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                                                .authorizationGrantType(CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                                                .scope(scope)
                                                .build();
        
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = 
                new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations);
        
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = 
                new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, clientService);
        
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = 
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID);
        
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
    }

}
```

Then we can access use this WebClient bean to send HTTP request to resource-server which will take care of fetching and managing the OAUTH2 token

```
webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:8080/api/private").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```